# Method of Wcf display at Client side in a grid asp.net

Tags: wcf-client

I have a table called Movies i want to select  some columns from it make a method at serverside WCF and diplay them in a grid on clientside Asp.net C#

table Movies
{ Title,Thumbnail,Genre,Rent,ID,OverDueRent}
and i want to dispaly Title,Genre,Thumbnail,Rent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get column by column id and than get data of whole column in a array variable and than fetch your desired data of column.